# using external files in rust tests

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I am writing a service that reads file content from the file, which location is read from env variable `FILE_LOCATION`.

```rust
fn my_function(){
    let path = match env::var("FILE_LOCATION") {
    ...
    let contents = match fs::read(&path) {
}
```

I have a test file `test_file.json` in:

```
proj
  resources
    test
      test_file.json
  src
    main.rs
  tests
    unit_tests.rs
```

In tests I can set `FILE_LOCATION`:

```
env::set_var("FILE_LOCATION", "path/to/test/file");
```

The question is what should be the value of `path/to/test/file`?

or in other words:

How can I access external files in Rust tests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cargo sets the environment variable `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` to the directory containing your `Cargo.toml` file. So you can get that environment variable, and append `resources/test/test_file.json` to it.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html for what environment variables Cargo sets.